# Python SUDS automatically appends xsi:type to complex type

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

I'm trying to call a web service method using python SUDS.

When trying to create a specific complex type SUDS appends `xsi:type="ns0:DeedDto"` to it.
Creating other types than this, SUDS does not append the xsi:type.

The problem here is that the recieving end cannot recognize this type and I then get this (specific) error:

```
WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceProxy.DeedDto' to type 'ServiceProxy.DeedDto[]
```

Here is the [WSDL URL](http://www.artvise.se/api/v1/mercuryapi/service.svc?wsdl)

Here is the actual code:

```
def create_case(self, case_data):
    """ CREATECASE """

    case_dto = self.client.factory.create('ns0:CaseDto')

    coordinates = self.client.factory.create('ns0:Coordinates')

    coordinates.Latitude = case_data.get('Latitude', None)
    coordinates.Longitude = case_data.get('Longitude', None)
    coordinates.SystemId = case_data.get('SystemId', None)

    case_dto.Coordinates = coordinates
    case_dto.CreatedByID = case_data.get('CreatedByID', None)
    case_dto.CreatedByName = case_data.get('CreatedByName', None)
    case_dto.CreatedDate = case_data.get('CreatedDate', None)
    case_dto.Description = case_data.get('Description', None)
    case_dto.Identifier = case_data.get('Identifier', None)
    case_dto.InboxGuid = case_data.get('InboxGuid', None)
    case_dto.ModifiedByID = case_data.get('ModifiedByID', None)
    case_dto.ModifiedByName = case_data.get('ModifiedByName', None)
    case_dto.ModifiedDate = case_data.get('ModifiedDate', None)
    case_dto.Name = case_data.get('Name', None)
    case_dto.ObjectGuid = case_data.get('ObjectGuid', None)
    case_dto.ObjectID = case_data.get('ObjectID', None)
    case_dto.ObjectTypeGuid = case_data.get('ObjectTypeGuid', None)
    case_dto.RefID = case_data.get('RefID', None)
    case_dto.StatusGuid = case_data.get('StatusGuid', None)
    case_dto.AnswerTypeGuid = case_data.get('AnswerTypeGuid', None)
    case_dto.EventDate = case_data.get('EventDate', None)
    case_dto.HtmlDescription = case_data.get('HtmlDescription', None)
    case_dto.InOutDate = case_data.get('InOutDate', None)
    case_dto.IncomingMediaTypeGuid = case_data.get(
        'IncomingMediaTypeGuid', None)
    case_dto.StartDate = case_data.get('StartDate', None)
    case_dto.StopDate = case_data.get('StopDate', None)

    """ COUNTERPART(S) """

    counterparts = []

    for counterpart in case_data['Counterparts']:
        counterpart_Dto = self.client.factory.create(
            'ns0:CounterpartDto')
        counterpart_Dto.Address1 = counterpart.get('Address1', None)
        counterpart_Dto.Address2 = counterpart.get('Address2', None)
        counterpart_Dto.Address3 = counterpart.get('Address3', None)
        counterpart_Dto.City = counterpart.get('City', None)
        counterpart_Dto.CompanyName = counterpart.get('CompanyName', None)
        counterpart_Dto.Country = counterpart.get('Country', None)
        counterpart_Dto.EMail = counterpart.get('EMail', None)
        counterpart_Dto.EMail2 = counterpart.get('EMail2', None)
        counterpart_Dto.FirstName = counterpart.get('FirstName', None)
        counterpart_Dto.HomePhone = counterpart.get('HomePhone', None)
        counterpart_Dto.LastName = counterpart.get('LastName', None)
        counterpart_Dto.MobilePhone = counterpart.get('MobilePhone', None)
        counterpart_Dto.OrganisationNumber = counterpart.get(
            'OrganisationNumber', None)
        counterpart_Dto.RealEstateArea = counterpart.get(
            'RealEstateArea', None)
        counterpart_Dto.RealEstateBlock = counterpart.get(
            'RealEstateBlock', None)
        counterpart_Dto.RealEstateUnit = counterpart.get(
            'RealEstateUnit', None)
        counterpart_Dto.SocialSecurityNumber = counterpart.get(
            'SocialSecurityNumber', None)
        counterpart_Dto.WorkPhone = counterpart.get('WorkPhone', None)
        counterpart_Dto.Zip = counterpart.get('Zip', None)
        counterparts.append(counterpart_Dto)

    case_dto.Counterparts = counterparts

    """ DEED(S) """

    deeds = []

    for deed in case_data['Deeds']:
        deed_Dto = self.client.factory.create('ns0:DeedDto')

        coordinates = self.client.factory.create('ns0:Coordinates')
        coordinates.Latitude = deed.get('Latitude', None)
        coordinates.Longitude = deed.get('Longitude', None)
        coordinates.SystemId = deed.get('SystemId', None)
        deed_Dto.Coordinates = coordinates

        deed_Dto.CreatedByID = deed.get('CreatedByID', None)
        deed_Dto.CreatedByName = deed.get('CreatedByName', None)
        deed_Dto.CreatedDate = deed.get('CreatedDate', None)
        deed_Dto.Description = deed.get('Description', None)
        deed_Dto.Identifier = deed.get('Identifier', None)
        deed_Dto.InboxGuid = deed.get('InboxGuid', None)
        deed_Dto.ModifiedByID = deed.get('ModifiedByID', None)
        deed_Dto.ModifiedByName = deed.get('ModifiedByName', None)
        deed_Dto.ModifiedDate = deed.get('ModifiedDate', None)
        deed_Dto.Name = deed.get('Name', None)
        deed_Dto.ObjectGuid = deed.get('ObjectGuid', None)
        deed_Dto.ObjectID = deed.get('ObjectID', None)
        deed_Dto.ObjectTypeGuid = deed.get('ObjectTypeGuid', None)
        deed_Dto.RefID = deed.get('RefID', None)
        deed_Dto.StatusGuid = deed.get('StatusGuid', None)
        deed_Dto.CaseObjectID = deed.get('CaseObjectID', None)
        deed_Dto.HtmlContent = deed.get('HtmlContent', None)
        deed_Dto.TextContent = deed.get('TextContent', None)

        """ FILE(S) """

        files = []

        for file_ in case_data['Files']:
            file_Dto = self.client.factory.create('ns0:FileDto')
            file_Dto.Data = file_.get('Data', None)
            file_Dto.Extension = file_.get('Extension', None)
            file_Dto.FileID = file_.get('FileID', None)
            file_Dto.FileName = file_.get('FileName', None)
            file_Dto.Size = file_.get('Size', None)
            files.append(file_Dto)

        deed_Dto.Files = files
        deeds.append(deed_Dto)

    case_dto.Deeds = deeds

    self.validate_request(case_dto, 'create_case')

    response = self.client.service.CreateCase(
        self.api_key, case_dto)
    return response
```

Looking at the actual service:

```
    Service ( Service ) tns="http://tempuri.org/"
   Prefixes (3)
      ns0 = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Artvise.Mercury.Base.DataContracts.API"
      ns1 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
      ns2 = "http://www.artvise.se/MercuryAPI/"
   Ports (1):
      (BasicHttpBinding_IService)
         Methods (21):
            CreateCase(xs:string apiKey, ns0:CaseDto caseDto, )
            CreateDeed(xs:string apiKey, ns0:DeedDto deedDto, )
            GetAnswerTypes(xs:string apiKey, )
            GetCase(xs:string apiKey, xs:int objectID, )
            GetCaseByIdentifier(xs:string apiKey, xs:string identifier, )
            GetCaseByRefID(xs:string apiKey, xs:string refID, )
            GetCasesByCounterpartSocialSecurityNumber(xs:string apiKey, xs:string socialSecurityNumber, xs:boolean includeDeeds, )
            GetCasesByInboxGuid(xs:string apiKey, ns1:guid inboxGuid, xs:boolean includeDeeds, )
            GetDeed(xs:string apiKey, xs:int objectID, )
            GetDeedByRefID(xs:string apiKey, xs:string refID, )
            GetDeedTypes(xs:string apiKey, )
            GetFile(xs:string apiKey, xs:int fileID, )
            GetFileByRefID(xs:string apiKey, xs:string refID, )
            GetInboxes(xs:string apiKey, )
            GetMediaTypes(xs:string apiKey, )
            GetStatuses(xs:string apiKey, )
            GetSystemMessages(xs:string apiKey, )
            SetCaseCoordinates(xs:string apiKey, xs:int objectID, ns0:CoordinatesDto coordinates, )
            SetCaseReference(xs:string apiKey, xs:int objectID, xs:string refID, )
            SetCaseStatus(xs:string apiKey, xs:int objectID, ns1:guid statusGuid, )
            Test()
         Types (27):
            ns0:AnswerTypeDto
            ns0:ArrayOfAnswerTypeDto
            ns0:ArrayOfCaseDto
            ns0:ArrayOfCounterpartDto
            ns0:ArrayOfDeedDto
            ns0:ArrayOfDeedTypeDto
            ns0:ArrayOfFileDto
            ns0:ArrayOfInboxDto
            ns0:ArrayOfMediaTypeDto
            ns0:ArrayOfStatusDto
            ns0:ArrayOfSystemMessageDto
            ns0:CaseDto
            ns0:CoordinatesDto
            ns0:CounterpartDto
            ns0:CreateObjectResult
            ns0:DeedDto
            ns0:DeedTypeDto
            ns0:FileDto
            ns0:InboxDto
            ns0:MediaTypeDto
            ns0:ObjectDto
            ns0:OperationResult
            ns0:StatusDto
            ns0:SystemMessageDto
            ns1:char
            ns1:duration
            ns1:guid
```

Seeing as this is an already built solution to which I'm only adding, I need to stick to SUDS.
Otherwise I would maybe look at something else.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using this (slightly stupid) solution:

```
self.client = Client(self.wsdl, plugins=[XSIValidator()])

class XSIValidator(MessagePlugin):
    """ Handles WSDL object differences """
    def sending(self, context):
        context.envelope = context.envelope.replace(
            ' xsi:type="ns0:DeedDto"', '')
```